# Class not found error during composer update

Tags: composer-php, shopware6

PHP 8.2.5
Shopware 6.4.20.2

on my dev machine, during `composer update` I get the following error, what could be the reason? (I'm using Devenv)

```
> [ ! -f vendor/autoload.php ] || $PHP_BINARY bin/console system:update:prepare
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\ClassNotFoundError^ {#44
  #message: """
    Attempted to load class "Docs" from namespace "Shopware\Docs".\n
    Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
    """
  #code: 0
  #file: "./vendor/shopware/core/Kernel.php"
  #line: 111
  trace: {
    ./vendor/shopware/core/Kernel.php:111 { …}
    ./vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:386 { …}
    ./vendor/shopware/core/Kernel.php:187 { …}
    ./bin/console:74 {
      › $application = new Application($kernel->getKernel());\r
      › $kernel->getKernel()->boot();\r
      › $application->setName('Shopware');\r
    }
  }
}
2023-05-09T19:43:36+00:00 [critical] Uncaught Error: Class "Shopware\Docs\Docs" not found
Script [ ! -f vendor/autoload.php ] || $PHP_BINARY bin/console system:update:prepare handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with error code 255
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you require the complete `shopware/platform` or only the parts that you need e.g. `shopware/core` and `shopware/administration`?

It seems like the docs bundle is expected, but it is not there.
As a fix, you can try to remove the `Shopware\Docs` bundle from the list of active bundles in `/config/bundles.php`.

Comment: Thank you, I require core / storefront and admin as per production template. Removing the Docs bundle solved the issue